# How to capture audio change in Linux?

Tags: linux, audio

I want to capture audio signal using terminal. I have to capture audio signal on some of available devices on picture below. What is command in terminal for capturing audio changes? Can i capture change without saving in some audio file, i only want to see if there is any audio change on some of those devices? [image: available devices]

Comment: "Capture audio **change** "? What do you mean ? then "capture change without saving in a file" ? What do you want to do with it ? Well ! In short, be precise : WHAT do you want to do with WHAT ?

Comment: I have some hardware device connected to audio input of my PC. When my hardware register some change it also gives audio output, I want to capture that output on some of devices on picture..

Comment: When i capture audio signal on some device, i should stop communication with my hardware, so that audio signal is like some confirmation that i finished job with hardware.

Comment: @skywalker It is a bit hard to discern what you are trying to achieve... I assume these devices you want to capture audio with are microphones? If so, do you want to visualize if the microphones are working without saving the recording to a file?

Comment: @telometto i want to capture audio output from hardware connected to my PC on some of those devices, so my question is, how can i capture audio signal on some of them.. as i said in previous comments this signal is just confirmation from hardware that he finished previous job... so main goal is to read input signal from hardware on those devices.. the picture is output from arecord -l command in terminal.

Comment: @skywalker Does [this](https://github.com/dpayne/cli-visualizer) fulfill your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ grep RUNNING /proc/asound/card*/pcm*/sub*/status command will give PCM device that is playing sound, so that helped me to capture audio change on some of outputs.