# How to detect sound signal on ALSA?

Tags: linux, alsa

I want to detect which of given devices produce sound signal, after some job is done. I work on MiB3 hardware that use Linux OS. On picture you can see list of devices (arecord -l command) available for capture, so can i somehow detect which of given devices produced sound of confirmation or there is another way to capture sound of confirmation that is actually only necessary thing for now. So how to stop some job when sound signal is produced that's the main goal (any ideas or similar solutions are welcome)? [image]

Comment: Is this question separate and different from your old question? [How to capture audio change in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/717929)

Comment: @Kusalananda it is, in this section i included completely different logic. Also this is based more on hardware device and ALSA is also included.